# Ajuda com erro foreach

Tags: php, mysqli

estou desenvolvendo um sistema que precisa subir 2 tipos de `img` uma pequena e uma grande para o banco de dados porem quando mando subir 3 `img` pequenas e 3 `img` grandes de teste meu `foreach` não sobe todas as `img` pequenas ou seja as suas respectivas ele sobe somente as 3 `img` grande ele ate sobe as 3 `img`pequena porem ele repete a primeira 3 vezes alguém pode me ajudar?

Codigo:

```
require"conexao.php";

    if(isset($_POST['port'])){  
    //dados que serão incluidos
    $nome = $_POST['galeria'];


foreach($_FILES['imgp']['tmp_name'] as $key => $name_temp){
        $name = $_FILES['imgp']['name'] [$key];
        $tmpnm = $_FILES['imgp']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $type = $_FILES['imgp']['type'][$key];
        $size = $_FILES['imgp']['size'][$key];

        $dir = "../images/small/portfolio/".$name;
        $mover = move_uploaded_file($tmpnm , $dir);

        foreach($_FILES['imgb']['tmp_name'] as $k => $n){
                $nomev = $_FILES['imgb']['name'] [$k];
                $t = $_FILES['imgb'] ['tmp_name'] [$k];
                $tipo = $_FILES['imgb']['type'][$k];
                $tam = $_FILES['imgb']['size'][$k];


        $dire = "../images/big/portfolio/".$nomev;
        $move = move_uploaded_file($t , $dire);


    if($mover&&$move){
             $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO portfolio(nome, img, type, size, img_big, tipo, tam) 
                values('$nome', '$name', '$type', '$size', '$nomev', '$tipo', '$tam')") or die (mysqli_error());
            if($sql){
                echo "foi";
            }
            else{
                echo "erro database";
            }
        }else{
            echo"<h1>Ocorreu um erro.</h1>";
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: O problema seria que as fotos grandes estão repetindo?

Comment: as pequenas estao repetindo as grande tao indo certo

Comment: se eu subo 3 pequenas e 3 grandes ele vai pegar a 1 pequena q subi e vai repetir ela 3x. mas a grande ele vai subir normal

Comment: provavelmente o seu problema seja o foreach das imagens grandes dentro do foreach das imagens pequenas, ele deveria repetir todas imagens grandes para cada imagem pequena.Não consigo ver a imagem pequena sendo repetida daqui, talvez se você fizer mais alguns testes e postar mais informações talvez fique mais fácil de te ajudarem.

Comment: ta certo o que voce disse eu ja usei o `var_dump()` para ver os resultados do primeiro `foreach` ele nao passa por todos ele sempre para na primeira `img` ja o segundo pega tudo normal. o que eu devo fazer para eles funcionarem do modo que ele suba todas as `img` pequena e todas as `img` grande?

Comment: Coloquei uma resposta com um código que deve ser aproximado do que você precisa, teste ele e informe o resultado depois.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesse caso está sendo utilizado um foreach das imagens grandes dentro das imagens pequenas, tente utilizar um foreach apenas.

O exemplo abaixo pode não funcionar 100%, pois considera que as imagens grandes tenham os mesmos índices das pequenas

```
if(isset($_POST['port'])){
//dados que serão incluidos
    $nome = $_POST['galeria'];


    foreach($_FILES['imgp']['tmp_name'] as $key => $name_temp){
        $name = $_FILES['imgp']['name'] [$key];
        $tmpnm = $_FILES['imgp']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $type = $_FILES['imgp']['type'][$key];
        $size = $_FILES['imgp']['size'][$key];

        $dir = "../images/small/portfolio/".$name;
        $mover = move_uploaded_file($tmpnm , $dir);

        $nomev = $_FILES['imgb']['name'] [$key];
        $t = $_FILES['imgb'] ['tmp_name'] [$key];
        $tipo = $_FILES['imgb']['type'][$key];
        $tam = $_FILES['imgb']['size'][$key];


        $dire = "../images/big/portfolio/".$nomev;
        $move = move_uploaded_file($t , $dire);


        if($mover&&$move){
            $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO portfolio(nome, img, type, size, img_big, tipo, tam)
values('$nome', '$name', '$type', '$size', '$nomev', '$tipo', '$tam')") or die (mysqli_error());
            if($sql){
                echo "foi";
            }
            else{
                echo "erro database";
            }
        }else{
            echo"<h1>Ocorreu um erro.</h1>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tudo se resolvia com um `foreach` intao eu tentei fazer mas eu tinha feito diferente acho que por isso deu erro eu passei os 2 `move_uploaded_file` no final do `foreach` acho q por isso que deu errado

Comment: Se os `move_uploaded_file` estivessem depois da condição do sql provavel que daria erro, fora isso não vejo nada "fora do comum".Outro detalhe é que mesmo esse código que te passei não está 100% a prova de erros, mas não é nada que mais uns testes de verificação e tratamento de exceção não resolvam.